# RxJava andlog for iOS development with Objective C

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, rx-java

I'm using RxJava for Android development and i think it's totaly awesome. My boss want me to port one of my apps to iOS platform. So i'm interesing - is there any similar tool for Objective-C? Or maybe you can share some reactive practices for iOS development? Google didn't give me a claer answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friends are using https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa but you could also try https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift
You can keep mostly the same approach as on Android, according to the different platform, of course.

Comment: Thx, i'll start with these libs.